# Why does changing the before_action get rid of this "undefined method 'admin' " error (Chapter 11 Hartl tutorial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Working through Michael Hartl's tutorial, I got stuck for a while in Chapter 11.3 "Manipulating Microposts".

Here are the two errors that I got:

> ERROR["test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in", UsersControllerTest, 2016-01-21 11:50:23 +0000]
>    test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (1453377023.37s)
>   NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
>               app/controllers/users_controller.rb:64:in`admin_user'
>               test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
>               test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:47:in`block in '
>           app/controllers/users_controller.rb:64:in `admin_user'
>           test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:48:in`block (2 levels) in '
>           test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:47:in `block in '
>
> ERROR["test_should_redirect_index_when_not_logged_in", UsersControllerTest, 2016-01-21 11:50:23 +0000]
>    test_should_redirect_index_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (1453377023.81s)
>   ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
>               app/views/users/_user.html.erb:4:in`_app_views_users__user_html_erb___1165587237033555937_81443380'
>               app/views/users/index.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb___836252608784755247_81359900'
>               test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:11:in`block in '
>           app/views/users/_user.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_users__user_html_erb___1165587237033555937_81443380'
>           app/views/users/index.html.erb:7:in`_app_views_users_index_html_erb___836252608784755247_81359900'
>           test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in '

After some research, I was able to get rid of the errors and get the tests to pass. However, even after all that work, I'm not sure why the change that I made caused the test to pass.

Here's what I did:

In the Users_Controller.rb I changed the 'before_action' for the logged_in_user from:

```
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
```

to:

```
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

That got rid of the admin? nil error. I'm still not sure why. Can anyone explain why the addition of the index and destroy caused the tests to pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Basically, it's because users have to be logged in to update their profile or delete a user. That's why :destroy and :update is added to the logged_in_user before filter. The logged_in_user method now being in ApplicationController from which the UserController inherits it. The MicropostControlle only needs :create and :destroy in that chapter.